# How to migare the docker containarized mongoDB to azure cosmosDB with Data Migration Service provided by azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have my mongo database within a docker container, which is hosted in an amazon ec2 instance. I wish to migrate the database to Azure CosmosDB with the help of data migration service provided by Azure. While setting up the DMS(Data Migration Service) project, I can't find a way to specify the source database, which resides in my ec2 instance. I gave the public ip of my instance in DMS as the source host. The docker container of mongo DB is open to the port 27107 of the instance. I have opened that port of instance to the public access as well. Still the migration service is not able to find the source database. If anyone can shed some light on this issue it will be so much helpful

Comment: This might fit better on ServerFault (it's not programming-related). That said: You would need to provide more specifics. You've mentioned a few things like port-opening, but there are many other details that go into data migration, as discussed in the docs.

Comment: Also, please be mindful of tags. For example, the `[cosmos]` tag explicitly states that it's not related to Cosmos DB. I've removed this, accordingly.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yea sure